# Use angular2 app using Azure blob storage and Azure proxy functions

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, proxy

I uploaded angular app "dist" folder into Azure blob storage.
I can run index.html from inside the blob, and it will run application.
Now, I want to create some Azure proxy function that will redirect to this blob and will run angular app.
But when I run this proxy, I get exception:

> error_handler.js:48 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'StorageUrl/ContainerName/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'FunctionUrl' and URL 'FunctionUrl/ContainerName'.
>   Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'StorageUrl/ContainerName/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'FunctionUrl' and URL 'FunctionUrl/ContainerName'.

Does anyone saw this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the error which is more about Angular's issue. The [official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) says:

> The router uses the browser's [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) for navigation. Thanks to `pushState`, you can make in-app URL paths look the way you want them to look, e.g. `localhost:3000/crisis-center`. The in-app URLs can be indistinguishable from server URLs.

And from [Mozilla pushState documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method):

> The new URL **must** be of the **same origin** as the current URL; **otherwise**, pushState() will throw an exception.